# How exactly is "Closed as a Duplicate" supposed to work?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39424/looking-forward-forwards-to-your-reply) about *"Looking forward/forwards to your reply"* was flagged as a possible dup of [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3885/forward-vs-forwards) titled *Forward vs Forwards*.

That second "original" just quotes a minimal "cook's tour" of usage from OED, which wouldn't help the second questioner at all with his specific context.

Is there (even in theory) any intention that EL&U should try to encourage only *one* page for, say, this particular word distinction? Or do we just allow that every one of the huge number of specific contexts where only one word or the other is normally used will eventually be asked about, and have its own dedicated question?

I don't know if the site supports anything like it, but I think the inarguably-correct answer on the second one should go into the first somehow, then the second really would be redundant and could be permanently deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to *merge* duplicate questions so all the answers are in one place, and the other question points to the first, with a redirect.

However, if you feel there should be a more complete answer on the first question, don't hesitate to add it, or edit the existing answer on the question to make it better.

If the two questions would have completely *different* answers, then perhaps they aren't duplicates?

Comment: In this particular case I'm sure the second question *is* a minor subset of the first. It only has a good *different* answer because it deals (almost peripherally) with the specific issue, whereas the answer in the first is both general and brief. What happens to the text of the second question, and comments thereto, if they're merged? What happens to any rep points or acceptances? Is "merging" the thing to do here? I don't think **I** have the tools/knowledge to effect or influence merging anyway.

Comment: @Fumble: the tools you have are editing, re-opening, and mod-flagging. Edit for clarity and/or to emphasize differences in the new question, or to generalize the original to better encompass the new one. Re-open if it is clear that the two questions are not the same. Mod-flag to request a merge (The end result of merging is that the new question remains as a stub with no answers, while the original question gains answers from both. Accumulated reputation remains, at least until the stub is deleted.)

Comment: @Shog9: Many thanks for giving me quite a bit of new information in a very clear form. I guess I don't really need to trouble you further by pressing on the question of whether *you* think the particular question I highlighted would in fact be better merged. I can just flag a request in this or similar situations and learn from the result how others feel. Thanks again.